# Spark - Collect kafka offsets to driver before writing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a high volume kafka topic that I'd like to write the batch offsets from. I'm currently using the following method. stream in this case is an InputDStream (I end up using the GenericRecord values in a DStream earlier).

```
val my_offsets = stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
  rdd.foreachPartition { iter =>
    val o: OffsetRange = offsetRanges(TaskContext.get.partitionId)
    val tOffsets = (o.topic, o.partition, o.untilOffset)

    writeOffsetsToMyDatasource(tOffsets)
  }
}
```

However this results in a write to whatever given datastore (MySQL, ZK, Hbase, etc) once per kafka partition which can have undesirable results when trying to do small time batches with a large number of partitions.

I cannot find a way to collect the offsetRanges to the driver, which would be much preferred, as one write per batch (for mysql, for example) with values specified would save a lot of unnecessary writes.

Answer (score 0):

`val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges`

your `offsetRanges` **is in driver**. You can serialize `offsetRanges` to preferred content then write it to whatever source you want.

By the way,
`val o: OffsetRange = offsetRanges(TaskContext.get.partitionId)`

your `offsetRanges` array always has equal length to number of partitions of `rdd`, with `foreachRDD` and default settings (`spark.streaming.concurrentJobs = 1`) I think the case `can have undesirable results when trying to do small time batches with a large number of partitions.` won't happen anyway.